# React map function not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map function that is returning results in the console, however it's not rendering in the DOM.

Here is my map function:

```
const featuredMakes = makes.filter(makes => makes.featured === true);
    var featured = Object.keys(featuredMakes).map(function(s){ 
        console.log(featuredMakes[s].title);  
        return (
            <Col className="mb-3">
                <Link
                    key={featuredMakes[s].title}
                    href={{ pathname: '/deal-list', query: query }}
                    as={{ pathname: '/filter', query: query }}
                    passHref
                >
                    <a>
                        <img
                            style={{ height: '80px', width: '80px' }}
                            src={featuredMakes[s].logo}
                            alt={featuredMakes[s].title + ' logo'}
                        />
                    </a>
                </Link>
            </Col>
        );
    });
```

And here is what's in my render call:

```
<Row>{this.renderFeaturedMakes(makes)}</Row>
```

The console is showing me everything correctly, however nothing is showing in the DOM. I am still learning React and ES2016. Any insight is helpful and appreciated!

Comment: And what is `renderFeaturedMakes`?

Comment: are you returning featured variable from renderFeaturedMakes function

Comment: Also if makes is an array, how is featuredMakes an object

Comment: Sorry `renderFeaturedMakes` is the name of my function from the first code block.  `featuredMakes` is returning the markup for each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to show them on the browser is to add `return` statement in `renderFeaturedMakes` method. Otherwise this method doesn't return nothing.

And if you want to write them in ES2016, it might help you.

```
const featuredMakes = makes.filter(makes => makes.featured === true);
const featured = Object.keys(featuredMakes).map(s => (
    <Col className="mb-3">
        <Link
            key={featuredMakes[s].title}
            href={{ pathname: '/deal-list', query: query }}
            as={{ pathname: '/filter', query: query }}
            passHref
        >
            <a>
                <img
                    style={{ height: '80px', width: '80px' }}
                    src={featuredMakes[s].logo}
                    alt={featuredMakes[s].title + ' logo'}
                />
            </a>
        </Link>
    </Col>
));
return featured;

// or just return instead of inserting `featured` variable
// return Object.keys(featuredMakes).map(s => {
```

Comment: Much cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting it. I was returning  from a var, when I needed to return directly.
Line 2 from above:

```
return Object.keys(featuredMakes).map(function(s){ 
        // console.log(featuredMakes[s]);  
        return (
```